# Iterate arraylist value on jsp after got response from ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp

I got the arraylist from the ajax response. How can I assign the values to `textbox` after getting the response from ajax through arraylist?

```
while(rs1.next())
{
            pabean.setAge(rs1.getString("patient_age"));
            pabean.setDalerg(rs1.getString("patient_drug_allergies"));
            pabean.setPmhistory(rs1.getString("patient_past_medical_history"));
            pabean.setDiet(rs1.getString("patient_diet"));
            pabean.setFhistory(rs1.getString("patient_family_history"));
            pabean.setTobbaco(rs1.getString("patient_smoke"));
            pabean.setDhistory(rs1.getString("patient_drug_history"));
            pabean.setAlco(rs1.getString("patient_alcohol"));
            pabean.setSleep(rs1.getString("patient_sleep"));
            pabean.setGhistory(rs1.getString("patient_ob_gyn_history")              
            pabean.setPatient_details_id(rs1.getInt("patient_details_id"));
            //uid = rs.getInt("patient_details_id");

}
           addressLists1.add(pabean);
           session.setAttribute("pagup", addressLists1);
           out.println(addressLists1);
```

Comment: Dear Rushant Patel..Can you please help us understand your issue posting little bit of  your code?

Comment: i got the arraylist object in response of ajax but how can i assign its value to textbox withot refreshing the page?

Comment: can you put the response you got?

Comment: In the jsp i have written

ArrayList<PatientDetailsBean> padetail = new ArrayList<PatientDetailsBean>();
        
                
        
        

        padetail = (ArrayList<PatientDetailsBean>)session.getAttribute("pagup");


System.out.println("padet----------------"+session.getAttribute("pagup"));
Got the response like this [com.bridghc.bean.PatientDetailsBean@15f9093f] and i am geeting the value also like System.out.println("pa--------------------------"+padetail.get(0).getAge());but how can i assign this value to age field without refreshing the jsp page?

Comment: what your `System.out.println` gives? *pa--------------------------(->what value here?)*

Comment: i am trying to assignn the value in textbox like

<input type="text"  id="txtage" name="txtage"  placeholder="Age" class="form-control" value="<%=padetail.get(0).getAge()%>"> but not geeting it but if i will do sysytem.out.println it show me the value.

Comment: i got pa--------------------------24

Comment: I guess may be the problem with parsing `"` quotes.

Comment: no that is not working

Answer (score 0):

You said you are getting this value from ajax call.

Do remember you can not get a java object in ajax response. because call is part of javascript and javascript can not access java object.

like the way you are printing the arraylist like out.println(addressList1); it is printing as [com.bridghc.bean.PatientDetailsBean@15f9093f] it's just a string representation of the addressList1 object which serves no purpose.

Second thing you have written code in jsp like

<input type="text" id="txtage" name="txtage" placeholder="Age" class="form-control" value="<%=padetail.get(0).getAge()%>">

so <%=padetail.get(0).getAge()%> is a java code which run at server when you demand for the page even before the ajax call was being made.

You can try this -

if you want to print the age in the jsp just print it on servlet like

out.println(padetail.get(0).getAge());

so now in the ajax response you will get the age.

now you can place that response value in the desired input with jquery like $('#txtage').val(responseData);

if you want your whole list on jsp in response of ajax it's better to use json use any of the json library like google gson or json.org and create json array instead of arraylist and then set mime type to "application/json" and then print it with out.print()
after that you can parse this json in ajax success call and use in whatever way you want.

Comment: There's no jQuery tag on the question, so you really need to make it clear that `$('#txtage').val(responseData);` is jQuery code and therefore won't work unless they're loading jQuery in their page as well. The regular JavaScript alternative works fine: `document.getElementById('txtage').value = responseData;`.